# Ruby require causing undefined local variable

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, path, rubygems, undefined

I am a complete noob to Ruby. I wish to execute a file that I have taken from an Amazon AWS IoT page, but I have problems with the initial require as below.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, I have installed ruby with *sudo apt-get install ruby-full* , and also *sudo gem install mqtt* . The file is called iot-connector.rb. I execute the file with *ruby iot-connector.rb* . It's obvious that it cannot find these require files, but how do I tell Ruby to find them. Thanks.

```
require ‘rubygems’
require ‘mqtt’

#more code....
```

The error I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
iot-connector.rb:1:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `‘rubygems’' 
for main:Object (NameError)
```

Comment: `require 'rubygems'`, by the way, has not been necessary for 11 years (since Ruby 1.9)

Comment: "It's obvious that it cannot find these require files" – Umm, no, it is not at all obvious. In fact, it is not even true. The error message says *nothing* about not finding a file. It says something about not finding a variable. In particular, it is telling you the name of the variable it is not finding, and that name is `‘rubygems’`. Note: the name that it is not finding is `‘rubygems’`, *not* `rubygems`. What does that tell you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use wrong type of quotes, use regular ones instead of backquotes:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mqtt'
```

Backquotes are used to run shell commands, btw. it's quite strange you get ruby errors here, I'd expect sth like:

```
[29] pry(main)> `rubygems`
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - rubygems
```

Comment: The original post has `‘` which is not a backtick, but `LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (U+2018)`

Comment: ah, that's the issue

Comment: Thanks alot. That quote was the problem. Silly me ) Now it works